# How to upload RData from ShinyFiles

Tags: r, shiny

I want to upload RData files using ShinyFiles, but I don´t know how to do it.

This is not working for me:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyFiles)



# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    shinyFilesButton('files', label='File select', title='Please select a file', multiple=FALSE),

    verbatimTextOutput("txt")
  )
)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  shinyFileChoose(input, 'files', root=c(root='/'), filetypes=c('', 'RData'))
  output$txt <- renderPrint(
    ls(parseFilePaths(roots= "/",selection = input$files))
  )



}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What´s wrong? I really dont understand how parseFilesPaths really works, because it get the route to the file, but I can not make it working. Also I have tried with

```
files< - load(parseFilePaths(roots= "/",selection = input$files)$type)
```

But it also didnt work...

Thansk!!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Here the solution (hope this will be helpfull for others)

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    shinyFilesButton('files', 'File select', 'Please select a file', FALSE),
    verbatimTextOutput('filepaths')
  )
)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  roots = c(wd='/home/developer/')


  reactivity <- reactive({ 
    shinyFileChoose(input, 'files', roots=roots, filetypes=c('', 'RData'))
    ruta <- parseFilePaths(roots, input$files)$datapath
    load(ruta)
    return(parseFilePaths(roots, input$files))
    })

  output$filepaths <- renderPrint({

 reactivity()

    })



}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I tried this with a file saved on the hard drive on my local machine. The `load` function returns an error message: `Warning: Error in gzfile: invalid 'description' argument`. I don't know if it is possible at all to use `shinyFileChoose` with local files.